# How do I fill a grid based shape with tris

Tags: opengl, textures, fill

I have a shape defined by an array of 2D points (clockwise around the shape) and a height value. The points conform to a grid layout with whole numbers, however there can be negative space in the shape. A simple example generated could be like the various blocks from Tetris.

I need to create surfaces and tris to fill the top side of the shape (the face that looks like a Tetris block) but I don't know how to break down the edge definition points into rectangles so I can create surfaces to cover it.

I'm sure this has been asked before but I don't know how to phrase it to find what I need.

Comment: So...[polygon triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "polygon triangulation". [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) explains a couple of algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above you want to research triangulation. A great method for beginners is called 'Ear Clipping'. Below is a link to a wonderful PDF that explains in detail the steps you need to take to implement it.

http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf

Comment: Bah, that's O(N^2), it's possible to do it in O(N) nowadays :)

Comment: Yea, it is not the most efficient version but it is a great introductory piece to the methods and logic behind it. And if you were really focused on performance you wouldn't be interested in ear-clipping :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in C++, you might use the CGAL library to do this:
http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Mesh_2/Chapter_main.html